# How to update webpage when you back from the redirected page?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, redirect

I use some logic to redirect to new page.

```
 return RedirectToAction("Index");
```

So when I back from this page via BACK BROWSER BUTTON I want to update "old" page automatically
so it should have default values.

Is it possible to do?

Comment: why would you use Response.Redirect(url); if you are using mvc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't really have anything to do with MVC. The back button behaviour is browser dependent, so the back button in IE will behave differently in FireFox. I know in FF if you use the back button on a page, it goes directly to the cached 'snapshot' of the last page and it won't refresh automatically, nor (as far as i know) will it execute code.